# Show posts from different years in the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, date, post, footer

I have a page with this code:

```
<?php
$year = date('Y');
$catquery = new WP_Query( "category_name=isonomia&year=$year" );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<?php the_time('Y-m-d'); ?> - <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

How can I put a link in the footer to show other years with the same code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one .

Called archive in your footer section.

```
<?php echo wp_get_archives('type=yearly'); ?>
```

You can edit format from archive.php from your current theme.

Comment: This code shows the posts in the last 12 month, I don't want this. I want a page that I can choose the year (in the footer) to show those posts (refresh the page).

Comment: Maybe I have not explained well. A single page, a single code, a variable "year". Change the year (number) of that variable, by a footer link, and refresh the page. Is it possible? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

user3240221 I'm also a little unclear of your desired outcome.  From what I read it sounds like you want to link to yearly archives based on a specific variable returned for the year value.

I stumbled onto this question while looking for something similar (I think).  I wanted to display a link to the yearly archive relative to a post date i.e. if it's a single post or post excerpt in archive from 2013 show a link to archives for 2013.

Here's what I dug up.

```
<?php $archive_year = get_the_time('Y'); ?>

<a href="<?php echo get_year_link( $archive_year ); ?>"><?php the_time('Y'); ?> archive</a>
```

This works in both archive / category pages and single posts types.  More on that at Wordpress Codex codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_year_link

This was also useful - codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Hopefully this will provide some insight.

UPDATE:

Ok, not sure if you Googled very far, but my search for "wordpress dropdown of yearly archives" came back with this - [Function_Reference/wp_get_archives](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives) The following code modified to your needs should do the trick.

```
<select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
  <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Year' ) ); ?></option> 
  <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'yearly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
</select>
```

If you need more google it - [https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+dropdown+of+yearly+archives](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress%20dropdown%20of%20yearly%20archives)

Comment: Hi @jarmerson, is not that. Here is the page: [link](http://isonomia.uji.es/comunicados/ ) It only shows the current year, and I want a link (or dropdown menu) in the footer to change the year. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for your effort. But I don't want show the information with the wp_get_archieves function. I just want change the $year variable and reload the page. Is it possible? I've googled, but don't find anything similar, just forms with GET-POST